# How Add NPOI to a Sandbox Sharepoint webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-web-part

I've a requirement to create a xsl file based on the list data. I can't use the default way to export list items into a excel file. 
I was testing the NPOI api but in my Visual web part it is not working...

Error message when debbuging:

> the type or namespace HSSFWorkbook is not valid in this scope

Can someone help me on this? Any other API I can use?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use owssver dll?

Comment: yes I do. The client want a file with a different format. The file will have some tabs to show the data for each list. (Tab1,Tab2,Tab3...)

Comment: Even though I haven't worked on it, but you are using Sandbox solution which are very restrictive. Do you see same error if you create a farm based solution?

Comment: I have not tested this, but the API worked well in a Console application...